# MSSQL Count multiple conditions in subquery or outer apply?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a query which currently has a few counts in the field selection part.

```
SELECT userid,
       (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1
        FROM   dbo.relationships
        WHERE  ( authorised IS NOT NULL
                 AND expired IS NULL
                 AND relationshipended IS NULL )
               AND ( mentorid = u.userid )) AS MenteeCount,
       (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1
        FROM   dbo.relationships AS Relationships_3
        WHERE  ( authorised IS NULL )
               AND (rejecteddate IS NULL)
               AND (mentorid = u.userid)) AS UnansweredRequests
FROM   users
```

Would it be better (more streamlined) to do this using an outer apply as I have two counts coming from the same external table?

e.g. Using `CASE WHEN`?

Comment: :D every answer is conflicting and a new solution added!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use apply, you can just use sum with case:

```
SELECT
    u.userId,
    MenteeCount = SUM(CASE WHEN  authorised IS NOT NULL AND expired IS NULL AND relationshipended IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    UnansweredRequests =SUM(CASE WHEN authorised IS NULL AND rejecteddate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
   users u
INNER JOIN
   dbo.relationships r
ON  u.userid = mentorid
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You should do the calculations in a single subquery:

```
SELECT u.userid, r.MenteeCount, r.UnansweredRequests
FROM users u OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN authorised IS NOT NULL AND expired IS NULL AND relationshipended IS NULL
                      THEN 1 ELSE 0
                 END) as MenteeCount
             SUM(CASE WHEN authorised IS NULL AND rejecteddate IS NULL
                      THEN 1 ELSE 0
                 END) as UnansweredRequests
      FROM  dbo.relationships r
      WHERE r.mentorid = u.userid
     ) r ;
```

That way, the processing for summarizing the relationships table is done only once for each `mentorid`.  Note that when specifying correlation clauses (for either subqueries or `apply`, you should always use fully qualified column names.  This helps avoid problems in the future.